# Get a Window's designed size without instantiating it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing a window positioning algorithm for my Winforms application. The windows that I'm going to be positioning will all be the same size, and are not resizable.

The logic requires me to know the size of the windows. I'd like to be able to access the design size of my window class. In other words, I'm looking for something like a static member or method of the Window class that will tell me what size the window was designed as.

I know that I could create my own static member/method that would report a hard coded value, but I want it to be generated automatically because if I later use the VS designer to resize the window, I don't want to have to remember to go back and update the hard coded values.

I also know that I could just temporarily create an instance of the window and get its actual size, but that feels like a kluge to me.

Any other options?

Comment: Did you try any of Win32 API?

Comment: You just can't, the actual window size is going to depend on the theme choices the user made, like the size of the font in the window title bar.  And most heavily on the video adapter's DPI setting, one that these days a lot of users change.  The egg *has* to come before the chicken, you must create the window to know the size.  The Load event is the first place you can find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

Either you instantiate the form and check the value. Or you parse the source file and read the values from there.

Both of these options assume that you are not programmatically changing the size of the form at run-time.

The easiest is to instantiate the form. And this isn't a kludge. This is the only way to get to the properties of an instance of an object.

Just remember to call `.Dispose()` on your form when you are finished with it.